# Hide the scrolling bar

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to hide(it should not be visible on screen) the vertical and horizontal scrolling bars, and make them visible only when overflow occurs?

Comment: `body {overflow: auto}`

Comment: `overflow: hidden` more help  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: overflow: auto, but browser show this to be different

Comment: Isn't this default behaviour in most browsers? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This OverFlow Auto On Your Css ParantDiv Class
When overflow Occurs Then Scrollbars Visible Otherwise In Hide Mode.

```css
.main{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  overflow:auto;
  border:1px solid;
}
.content{
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<div class="content">
  <h1>Content Here</h1>
  <h1>Content Here</h1>
  <h1>Content Here</h1>
  <h1>Content Here</h1>
  <h1>Content Here</h1>
  <h1>Content Here</h1>
  <h1>Content Here</h1>
  <h1>Content Here</h1>
  <h1>Content Here</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```